# Can I manually set the size of GeoServer's tiles?

Tags: geoserver, labeling, tiles, sld

I'm using GeoServer to generate a street name overlay that we can use with our various basemaps.  It works great, but the names repeat too often to be truly beautiful.  I've tried bumping up the [repeat](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/labeling.html#repeat) option in the SLD, but high values are being ignored, and the label is generated once per tile.

The simplest workaround I can think of is to simply bump up the size of the tiles for the layer, but I can't find an option that'll let me set that.  Does this option exist in GeoServer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using GWC to make your tiles?

Comment: @iant - Yes, it is enabled.  I haven't done any GWC-specific configuration, though; it's working "out-of-the-box," so to speak.

Comment: Adding `tiled=true` to my WMS request seems to allow labels to cross tile boundaries.  That's improved things quite a bit, though the "repeat" parameter is still a bit sketchy.